# Escaping in a ILIKE query

Tags: database, postgresql, escaping

I need to do a query that search for a text with **'Nome % teste \  / '** as prefix. I'm doing the query using:

**where "name" ILIKE 'Nome a% teste \ /%' ESCAPE 'a'** (using a as escape character).

There is a row that match this, but this query returns nothing. Removing the slash (**'Nome % teste \'**), it works. But I don't see why the **slash** is a problem, since the default escape is a **backslash** and I've changed it to **'a'** in this test.

There is something that I'm missing? (I've consulted TFM)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the "ESCAPE" specifier

```
WHERE "name" ILIKE 'Nome ~% teste \\/' ESCAPE '~'
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-matching.html

Note: you still need to have the \ twice for the string parser.

Without the ESCAPE you would need to do

```
WHERE "name" ILIKE 'Nome \% test \\\\/'
```

( 4 \ 's to represent one literal \ )

---

> Thanks, but I still have the original issue with the slash. Searching with
>
> ```
> WHERE "name" ILIKE 'Nome \% test \\\\/%'
> ```
>
> don't give me a result, while
>
> ```
> WHERE "name" ILIKE 'Nome \% test \\\\%'
> ```
>
> (removed the slash, that is present in the row) works as expected.  – Kknd

its possible your string does not have a literal "/" like you specified. you possibly have a null, or other whitespace character inbetween. Or possibly, you have / in a different character set.

I would attempt to use this to test for that possible scenario

```
 WHERE "name" ILIKE 'Nome \% ' AND "name" ~* '\\.{1,10}/'
```

which will return lines that have / separated by something( but not lines with no separation )

Comment: Thanks, but I still have the original issue with the slash. Searching with WHERE "name" ILIKE 'Nome \% test \\\\/%' don't give me a result, while WHERE "name" ILIKE 'Nome \% test \\\\%' (removed the slash, that is present in the row) works as expected.

Comment: Thanks, this is a strange issue, I will try so change the charset

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried just using the backslash to escape it like this:

```
where "name" ILIKE 'Nome \% teste \\\/';
```